# Android bottom navigation bar overlapping Spinner. Set Spinner dropdown height / margin

Tags: android, android-layout, android-spinner

There is an interesting issue I stumbled upon while working on an Android Honeycomb project. As you can see in the image below, while expanding a Spinner in a dialog, the navigation bar at the bottom overlaps it. Thus, the element at the bottom can not be selected.

In order to fix this I tried using `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in the Spinner widget. It did not work. Also I noticed that we have an XML Attribute for dropdown width, `android:dropDownWidth`, but none for height.

[image: Navigation Bar overlapping Spinner]

Here is the XMl layout for the 3 Spinners:

```
    <TableRow>

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/order_dialog_category_code_Spinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/order_dialog_packing_code_Spinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/order_dialog_product_Spinner"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
    </TableRow>
```

I will keep testing and hope to find a solution soon but it is an interesting issue and it deserved to be posted.

I did not test in Android ICS yet but I think it might act the same.

**EDIT**

I managed somewhat of a fix by using the `android:layout_marginBottom` attribute for the Spinners. It did solve the issue but now I have the margin in the dialog view as well and I don't want that.

[image: Spinner overlapping temporary fix]

Does anyone know how to set the margin only for the dropdown resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research it seems that you can not manipulate the height of the Spinner dropdown, or any other of it's layout attributes.

This is because the dropdown is actually a popup dialog that cannot be accesed from the Spinner View.

This answer states it clear: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1918655/529138

So it seams that I have to use `android:layout_marginBottom` as specified in the question.

Comment: I got the same problem, really annoying bug, have you found a better fix by now?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I did not revisit the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Even i faced the same issue. Unlike your screen my screen has just one option. so i made a fix changing the android:spinnerMode:"dialog".

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/dialog_spinner"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >
```

This would show your list in a new dialog. Just in case might be helpful for people searching with similar problem.